# ^@ when placing a string from cmd.exe in vim-airline

Tags: statusline, plugin-airline

I have defined the following function

```
let g:conda_activate = 'myenv'

" Get conda virtual environment
function Condaenv(env)
    return system("conda activate ". a:env. " && call echo %CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%")
endfunction

augroup Condaenvget
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * let g:conda_env = Condaenv(g:conda_activate)
augroup END
```

and then I place `g:conda_env` in one section of `vim-airline` as it follows

```
au User AirlineAfterInit  :let g:airline_section_b = airline#section#create(['(%{g:conda_env})'])
```

However, what I see in the `statusline` is the following

[image]

If I `:echo Condaenv(g:conda_activate)` or just `:echo g:conda_activate` I don't see such a `^@` .
Am I doing something wrong or is it a potential bug of `vim-airline`?
If so, I'll consider to open an issue on their issue tracker.

Comment: Try `trim()`ing the result of `system()`; I suspect a newline getting translated to a null

Comment: And for Windows, incorporate `trim()` with `system()` into a custom `System()` function. After switching to Windows, I kept having to trim here and trim there. What a mess.

Comment: Instead of using `system()`, I would make use of `systemlist()` which should automatically trim the trailing carriage return + line feed. BTW: Are you sure you want to call `conda activate` really all the time, e.g. for any key you press? That seems excessive and may slow down vim

Comment: The `trim` solution works. The `systemlist` solution returns a list so I have to access it to extract a string. @ChristianBrabandt not really, I don't want to call `conda activate` for any key press but  I want to call it only at Vim startup. Or, even better, I want to call it every time a virtual environment has changed, but I don't think Vim has defined such an event :D So, I am fine to call it only at Vim startup - isn't `VimEnter` the Vim startup event?!?

Comment: Why would you use `join` if you are only interested in the last line? Just use `systemlist()[0]` or `systemlist()[-1]`